# WCF operation result

Tags: wcf

There are two users: `ManagerOne` and `ManagerTwo`. Before use my service they must login.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    int _userID = -1;
    public bool LogIn(int userID, string password)
    {
       if( UserCheck(userID, password) )
         _userID = userID;
       else
         throw new FaultException<InvalidUserFault>(new InvalidUserFault());
    }
}
```

After login they can run `GetSome()` operation. This `operation` return some my `DataContract`. And this `operation` can run only `ManagerOne`. If `ManagerTwo`run `GetSome()`, `operation` must return error. The question is: what is best practice - `return OperationResult<T>` or `FaultException` (in THIS scenario)?

See some code:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    int _userID = -1;
    public bool LogIn(int userID, string password){...}
    public OperationResult<SomeDataContract> GetSome()
    {
        if(_userID != 101)
          return new OperationResult<SomeDataContract>()
              {
                  Result = false,
                  ResultMessage = "User hasn't permission",
                  ReturnValue = null;
              };
        .....
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    int _userID = -1;
    public bool LogIn(int userID, string password){...}
    public SomeDataContract GetSome()
    {
        if(_userID != 101)
          throw new FaultException<MyFaultContract>(new MyFaultContract("User hasn't permission"));
    }
}
```

In classic app I would use GenericResult, because I think it is not `exception`. But what about `WCF`? Is `FaultException` normal practice for my scenario?

Comment: yes. You can use `FaultException` to provide your client with enough error details.

Comment: But I think exception should be thrown in abnormal situation. I'm right? In my scenario Service refuse request - it's normal behavior.

Comment: it's normal and that's just a business requirement I guess.

Comment: always use FaultException in WCF. it is the standard practice when developing WCF Services.#